# Building iPhone application with iOS 3.2 SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am about to send my iPhone application to Apple. I have tested the application on the simulator with iOS 3.2 and I haven't got it to crash because of using methods from a later SDK. Since the target of my application will be 3.2 and upwards I wonder if it is possible to build the application in XCode with the 3.2 SDK, or do something else that reports if I use methods not available in that SDK version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Apple does want you to check if your app is compatible with iOS 4.0. This used to be asked by the application loader.

But you can just build your app with the 4.* SDK as long as the iOS Deployment target is set to the minimum version that you will support.